# Gitolite and gitweb

Tags: gitolite, gitweb

Weird permissions problem with gitweb: -- repositories in the "www-data" group (`chgrp -R www-data`) are seen in the web interface, but repositories still in the default "git" group aren't:

```
> ll repositories
drwxr-x---  7 git www-data 4096 Oct 16 14:34 this_works.git/
drwxr-x---  7 git git      4096 Oct 14 17:07 this_doesnt_work.git/
```

www-data is in the "git" group (done using `usermod -a -G git www-data`):

```
> groups www-data
www-data : www-data git
```

Users in the right group can read the repositories because .gitolite.rc contains:

```
UMASK =>  0027
```

Both repositories are in projects.list, and are otherwise identical.  Checked with `sudo su www-data` that www-data can view the contents of both repositories.